# how to insert multiple rows intered in DataGridview into database table at once

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, linq-to-entities

I have an Unbound DataGridview that supports adding new records. The user can enter one or more records into this DataGridview and at this time, nothing should be saved.

When a user is done with entering records, I want to them to click a button and have all the rows in the DataGridview inserted into a table.

**I am using Linq To Entities.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulk insert is not supported by EF directly. You can use [SqlBulkCopy Class (System.Data.SqlClient)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx). [Here](http://cgeers.com/2011/05/19/entity-framework-bulk-copy/) is a good article.